# Writing a dockerfile & docker compose script to setup a Vue3 application

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to setup my Vue3 production build on docker using a Dockerfile and a docker-compose.yml file. The  production build loads infinitely and hangs on the browser. It however works okay on Vercel and on my local machine, which makes me suspect it could be my docker configurations.

This is the current Dockerfile that I am using

```
FROM node:18-alpine

RUN npm install -g npm@10.1.0

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/node_modules

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/dist

RUN apk add python3 make g++ && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN npm install -g serve

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm cache verify

RUN npm install     

COPY . .

RUN rm -rf dist

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["serve", "-s", "dist", "-p", "8080"]
```

This is the configuration on the docker-comose.yml file

```
 customer:
    build:
      context: ./customer
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    image: package/customer:latest
    ports:
      - "443:8080"
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        max_attempts: 3
    volumes:
      - ./customer:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
      - /usr/src/app/dist
    restart: always
```

What could i be doing wrong?